# Why a group_by + summarise of thousands of observations yielding a dataframe 1x1?

Tags: r, group-by, summarize

Please, consider the following:

`edx2` is a dataframe with 9000055 obs. of  8 variables;

`movieId` is a column of edx2 with more than 10,000 levels;

`rating` is a # column of edx2; mean(edx2$rating) is a valid number.

`naive` is a # constant;

My objective with the code below is to get a table relating a # outcome for each `movieId` level:

```
movie_dev <- edx2 %>%
group_by(movieId) %>%
summarize(movieid_dev = mean(rating - naive))
```

The result I'm getting is a 1x1 dataframe, instead of +10,000 x 2 variables.
I don't understand why.
Any clues?

Comment: Maybe there is conflict with other package. Try a new fresh `R` session. Sometimes `plyr` affects `dplyr` functions.

Comment: It could be returning a nested loop for some reason, what is the value of the 1x1 data frame?

Comment: Daniel, the value is a number 1.75 ...

Comment: Try with `dplyr::summarize`